# Linq To Xml problems using XElement's method Elements(XName)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, element, xelement

I have a problem using Linq To Xml.

A simple code. I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/directory file.xsd">
<contact>
 <name>aaa</name>
 <email>email@email.ext</email>
 <birthdate>2002-09-22</birthdate>
 <telephone>000:000000</telephone>
 <description>Description for this contact</description>
</contact>
<contact>
 <name>sss</name>
 <email>email@email.ext</email>
 <birthdate>2002-09-22</birthdate>
 <telephone>000:000000</telephone>
 <description>Description for this contact</description>
</contact>
<contact>
 <name>bbb</name>
 <email>email@email.ext</email>
 <birthdate>2002-09-22</birthdate>
 <telephone>000:000000</telephone>
 <description>Description for this contact</description>
</contact>
<contact>
 <name>ccc</name>
 <email>email@email.ext</email>
 <birthdate>2002-09-22</birthdate>
 <telephone>000:000000</telephone>
 <description>Description for this contact</description>
</contact>
```

I want to get every contact mapping it on an object Contact. To do this I use this fragment of code:

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + this.filesource);
XElement XRoot = XDoc.Root;
//XElement XEl = XElement.Load(this.filesource);
var results = from e in XRoot.Elements("contact") 
 select new Contact((string)e.Element("name"), (string)e.Element("email"), "1-1-1", null, null);
List<Contact> cntcts = new List<Contact>();
foreach (Contact cntct in results) {
 cntcts.Add(cntct);
}
Contact[] c = cntcts.ToArray();
// Encapsulating element
Elements<Contact> final = new Elements<Contact>(c);
```

Ok just don't mind that all: focus on this:

When I get the root node, it is all right, I get it correctly.

When I use the select directive I try to get every  node saying: from e in

```
XRoot.Elements("contact")
```

OK here's the problem: if I use: from e in XRoot.Elements() I get all contact nodes, but if I use: from e in XRoot.Elements("contact") I GET NOTHING: Empty SET.

OK you tell me: Use the other one: OK I DO SO, let's use:
`from e in XRoot.Elements()`, I get all nodes anyway, THAT's RIGHT BUT HERE COMES THE OTHER PROBLEM:
When Saying:   `select new Contact((string)e.Element("name"), (string)e.Element("email"), "1-1-1", null, null);` I Try to access `<name>, <email>`... I HAVE TO USE .Element("name") AND IT DOES NOT WORK TOO!!!!!!!!WHAT THE HELL IS THIS????????????? IT SEEMS THAT I DOES NOT MATCH THE NAME I PASS But how is it possible. I know that Elements() function takes, overloaded, one argument that is an XName which is mapped onto a string. Please consider that the code I wrote come from an example, It should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - one word of advice: if you post code snippets, or XML fragments, **please** highlight those lines and click on the "code" button (101 010) in the editor toolbar to properly format them. Makes your post just that much nicer and more readable!

Answer (score 16):

Pretty easy: there's a XML namespace in play, which you're ignoring:

```
<data xmlns="http://www.example.com"  
      **************************
```

You need to add that to your Linq-to-XML queries!

Something like:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com";
```

and then

```
XRoot.Elements(ns + "contact")
```

and of course, also use the XML namespace when accessing the child elements:

```
var results = from e in XRoot.Elements("contact") 
              select new Contact(e.Element(ns + "name").Value, 
                                 e.Element(ns + "email").Value, 
                                 "1-1-1", null, null);
```

That should help. See the MSDN docs on [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This is probably my only complaint with linq2xml API.  Most software I've worked on isn't interested in the namespace, but code is needed to handle it in any case.

Comment: @Frank: but what good is it to have namespaces (designed specifically to disambiguate elements of the same name) when your API blatantly ignores them?? Doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, really....

Comment: REALLY... I TRY IT NOW, Anyway, Thanks thanks thanks, it's incredible, you answered me so fastly.... Thanks for real, i'll let you know how it is going... Just have to try :)

Comment: OK IT WORKS... THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I didn0t really focused on namespaces :) Thank you very much!

Comment: namespaces are useful in XML but rarely do I need to read from different namespaces.  The need to respecify the namespace constantly seems like overkill.

Comment: You can ignore namespaces if you like: XRoot.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "contact")

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved it like that because I didn't had a namespace in my XML:

```
xmldoc.Root.Elements("contact");
```

I forgot to use the "Root" method.