# WP7 Linq to XML to get a child element of an XElement by name

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I know this is a somewhat easy question, but I haven't been able to make it work even after looking at answers on SO and LINQ to XML tutorials. I'm using Windows Phone 7, but I don't think that should make a difference.

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<response xmlns="http://anamespace.com/stuff/">
    <error code="ERROR_CODE_1">You have a type 1 error</error>
</response>
```

I have the XML above loaded into an XElement. I want to get the "error" node. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754458/linq-to-xml-problems-using-xelements-method-elementsxname) says you need to handle the namespace. I've tried my query with and without the namespace and it doesn't work either way.

Query with namespace:

```
private object ParseElement(XElement responseElement)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://anamespace.com/stuff/";
    IEnumerable<XElement> errorNodes = from e in responseElement.Elements(ns + "error") select e;
}
```

Query without namespace:

```
private object ParseElement(XElement responseElement)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> errorNodes = from e in responseElement.Elements("error") select e;
}
```

The errorNodes variable never gets populated with XElements. The tutorials I've read all use this notation for selecting an element by name, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This codes *Works on my Machine*™:

```
XElement response = XElement.Parse(
@"<response xmlns=""http://anamespace.com/stuff/"">
    <error code=""ERROR_CODE_1"">You have a type 1 error</error>
</response>");

XNamespace ns = "http://anamespace.com/stuff/";

XElement error = response.Element(ns + "error");

string code = (string)error.Attribute("code");
string message = (string)error;

Console.WriteLine(code);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

My machine runs regular .NET 4 though, so maybe you can run this code and check if it works for WP7.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're reading the whole document instead of the `error` elements?

Does it work if you use `Descendants` instead of `Elements`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanGetErrorElements()
{
    string xml = @"
<response xmlns=""http://anamespace.com/stuff"">
<error code=""ERROR_CODE_1"">You have a type 1 error</error>
</response>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XNamespace ns = "http://anamespace.com/stuff";
    var errorNodes = from e in doc.Descendants(ns + "error") 
                     select e;
    Assert.IsTrue(errorNodes.Count() > 0);
}
```